# Can we downgrade InstallShield project?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011, installshield-2013

I'm having a InstallShield 2013 project. Can I open this project in InstallShield 2011 ?

Can we open InstallShield Projects of higher version in the lower version of InstallShield ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see: [Converting InstallShield Projects From One Version to Another](http://www.installationdeveloper.com/541/converting-installshield-projects-from-one-version-to-another/)

It would seem we used to be able to but lost the ability with IS2010.

Comment: Hi Christopher,
I tried your suggestion. But I'm facing some issues with setup.rul after converting it. I'm not able to call some functionality into my custom actions. So can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do directly now.
But, if it is XML format, change the value of SchemaVersion using notepad, let's say 783 is for 2020 R2 and for 2016 it is 777.
If it is binary format then change the extension to msi and open with orca and change the value and rename the extension back to ism